# c++ cannot create object with identifier

Tags: c++

I already searched everywhere and I think this is really basic problem but I checked some other people code and they were using the same method to create an object with a unique ID that's why I'm not understanding why it doesnt work with me.

So here's the class Enemy:

```
class cEnemy{
public:
       //code that doesnt matter
};
```

So what i want to do is basically create 10 Enemies and each one will have a unique identifier(0...9), so what im doing is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       Enemy[i] = new cEnemy;
}
```

Right now it already gives me an error:
error C2065: 'Enemy' : undeclared identifier

But if instead of writing Enemy[i] if i write Enemy[5] it works fine. I think im missing something.

Why? I saw this code exactly the same in other application and it works...

So my objective as I said it's to create 10 enemies with unique Id's and then to have access to each one but as you see i can't even create them.

Thanks in advance.

PS: The class and main are in the same cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::array<cEnemy, 10> Enemy;
for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
    Enemy[i] = new cEnemy;
}
```

You have to create an array before you can use it.  The error you're getting is the same as if you were try to do:

```
arrInt[i] = someInt;
```

Before having done:

```
int arrInt[someCount];
```

Comment: You're correct of course, but I'd advise using a  `std::array<cEnemy, 10>` (or a `vector`) to avoid all the horrible pointer decay things that happen when passing C arrays to functions,  which can be pretty confusing to newcomers.

Comment: @nhgrif

Thanks a lot.  So to be sure if i understood, with that code we created an array that has 10 objects of the type cEnemy, and with the for cycle, in each position of the array we make a new enemy?

Let's say that the Enemy has X position and I want to access the position of the enemy saved in array with "id" 5: I just need to do this?

Invasor[5]->getX();

Im a little confused

Comment: Well, in this example, the array is called `Enemy`.  But if your `cEnemy` class has a method called `getX()`, and you want to call that on an element of the array, then I believe you've got the right syntax: `Enemy[5]->getX();`  I'm not perfectly familiar with `C++`, so no guarantees, but try it out.